# How to go about indexing 300,000 text files for search?

Tags: database, search

I have a static collection of over 300,000 text and html files. I want to be able to search them for words, exact phrases, and ideally regex patterns. I want the searches to be fast.

I think searching for words and phrases can be done by looking up a dictionary of unique words referencing to the files that contain each word, but is there a way to have reasonably fast regex matching?

I don't mind using existing software if such exists.

Comment: You **don't mind using exsiting software**? Seriously this problem is too complex for one person to implement in a timely manner. This doesn't belong here.

Comment: Yes, fast regex searching is possible, as demonstrated by http://www.google.com/codesearch. But I have no idea how they did that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider Lucene http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html

Comment: Does Lucene support searches with regular expressions?

Comment: Yes, see http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/api/contrib-regex/org/apache/lucene/search/regex/RegexQuery.html

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a bunch available in the market which will help you achieve what you want, some are open-source and some comes with pricing:

Opensource:

[elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) - based on lucene

[constellio](http://www.constellio.com/) - based on lucene

[Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/features.html) - based on C++

[Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) - built on top of lucene

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at Microsoft Search Server Express 2010: http://www.microsoft.com/enterprisesearch/searchserverexpress/en/us/technical-resources.aspx

Comment: Does the Microsoft Search Server support searches with regular expressions?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is possible but I am not an expert on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.webdistortion.com/2011/05/29/open-source-search-engines/